# Watson Discovery Passage Length

Tags: watson, watson-discovery

I am finding that the passages returned by Discovery are generally very good choices... but they are too short and truncated at odd points... even mid sentence. A couple of questions:

Is there a way to control the passage length returned?

Is there a way to bring the user directly to the passage within the full document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like they [Discovery Query API](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery/api/v1/?curl#query-collection) now supports controlling the passage length, although the SDK's (Java and NodeJS) haven't been updated yet to support it.

```
passages.characters     The approximate number of 
              query     characters that any one passage should have. 
            integer     The default is 400. The minimum is 50. The
                        maximum is 2000. Note: The passages.characters 
                        parameter is supported only on private
                        collections. It is not supported in the 
                        Watson Discovery News collection.
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Currently, passage length is fixed at 200 characters, though it will generally not be exactly 200 as passages start and end at word boundaries.

2) No.

Comment: Thanks much Anastas

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with Watson Discovery. The answer seems to be if you need longer answers, to divide your documents into short sub-documents and make those part of your collection. For instance, I use discovery with my syllabus to help students who have questions about class and university policies. I divide each sub-section into its own document. Discovery can then produce the entire document (which is not more than a paragraph).